# Why when I made my constraint relative to the superview's bottom did it operate from the superview's top? And is it now right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have the following code:

```
self.noArticlesView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.frame.size.height)];
UIImage *backgroundPattern = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-articles-background.png"];
self.noArticlesView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundPattern];

[self.view addSubview:self.noArticlesView];

UIImage *noArticlesImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-articles-icon.png"];
UIImageView *noArticlesImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:noArticlesImage];
noArticlesImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.noArticlesView addSubview:noArticlesImageView];

NSLayoutConstraint *horizontalCenterConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:noArticlesImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.noArticlesView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[self.noArticlesView addConstraint:horizontalCenterConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *verticalPlacementConstrant = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:noArticlesImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.noArticlesView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:-230.0];
[self.noArticlesView addConstraint:verticalPlacementConstrant];
```

Basically, I'm adding a view (called `noArticlesView`) on top of the view controller's view, and this view displays a message saying there's no content currently added (in the case that there isn't, of course).

To that view I then add an image as a subview as an indicator of this.

But when I change the above constraint on the image to have the property `toItem:self.view` and add it to `self.view` instead of `self.noArticlesView` it pushes it from the top of the view and not the bottom (i.e. 200 as the constant will push it 200px from the top).

I got it sorted out by setting the image's constraint relative to `noArticlesView` instead of `self.view`, but I'm still curious for the behavior (I'm still learning Auto Layout and want to get a grasp of it).

---

Also, is what I'm doing now correct? If I want it to be be positioned 230px from the bottom, is setting the constant to -230 the way to go? Is setting constants as negative bad form or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced weird things like this too, and I suspect it is because the superview (in your case `self.view`) has no height--it doesn't resize based on its superviews. That means that the bottom of `self.view` is equal to the top, making it look like the constraint works from the top. You can try two things to verify this theory:

1. Inspect `self.view`'s frame (the height will be 0)
2. Set `self.view.clipsToBounds = YES` (your views, including the background view, won't show because they're clipped)

This is (or might be) only an explanation of what's going on, I am not sure what the right way to deal with this is.

As far as your other question goes: it is perfectly valid to do it that way, although there often is a better way to do it. Ask yourself "why is is -230"? If that's because the image is 230 tall, then use `-noArticlesImage.size.height`. If 230 just happens to be the number that makes the whole view look best, it's fine to use (though best practice dictates using a constant or preprocessor macro to define the 230).

Comment: Couldn't ask for a better answer. 230 is indeed just a magic number, but I'll keep that in mind, thank you. :)